# How do you prevent the saving of a nested object but still save the main object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a 'notes' object nested inside multiple other objects, for example 'user'. I want to only add/save a new note if someone has filled out something in the note_text field. I thought I found a way but it stops the saving of the rest of the object as well due to the error.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notes

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :notes

end  

class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  before_save :check_for_blank_note

  def check_for_blank_note
    if self.note_text.nil? || self.note_text.blank?
      false
    else
      true
    end
  end
end
```

I was hoping to just stop the save on the notes and let the user be updated and saved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `:reject_if` to silently drop any record that does not pass your logic:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :notes, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['note_text'].blank? }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always add a validation that precludes empty notes from being saved:

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :note_text, presence: true
end
```

This will trigger an exception on saving if you use `save!` so you may want to screen out any invalid notes:

```
before_save :remove_empty_notes

def remove_empty_notes
  self.notes.reject! { |note| !note.valid? }
end
```